# Error when trying to compare strings in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have the following in my script:

```
fw=$2
if [ "$fw" == "zf" ]
then
  public_dir=$dir/current/public
else
  public_dir=$dir/current
fi
```

But I get the following error when I run it:

```
./generatevhost.sh: 15: [: zf: unexpected operator
```

I've lookup pages explaining how to compare strings and they describe like so. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're not using BASH or ksh. Try this if condition by replacing `==` by `=`:

```
fw="$2"
if [ "$fw" = "zf" ]
then
   public_dir=$dir/current/public
else
   public_dir=$dir/current
fi
```